# regex to remove words from a list that are not A-Z a-z (exceptions)

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I would like to remove non-alpha characters from a string and convert each word into a list component such that:

```
"All, the above." -> ["all", "the", "above"]
```

It would seem that the following function works:

```
re.split('\W+', str)
```

but it does not account for corner cases.

For example:

```
"The U.S. is where it's nice." -> ["the", "U", "S", "is", "where", "it", "s", "nice"]
```

I want the period removed but neither the apostrophe or the periods in "U.S."

My idea is to create a regex where spaces are broken up but then remove extra punctuation:

```
"I, live at home." -> ["I", "live", "at", "home"] (comma and period removed)
"I J.C. live at home." -> ["I", "J.C.", "live", "at", "home"] (acronym periods not removed but end of sentence period removed)
```

What I'm trying to do becomes sufficiently difficult for sentences like:

```
"The flying saucer (which was green)." -> ["...", "green"] (ignore ").") 
"I J.C., live at home." -> ["I", "J.C.", "..."] (ignore punctuation)
```

Special case (strings are retrieved from raw text file):

```
"I love you.<br /> Come home soon!" -> ["..."] (ignore breakpoint and punctuation)
```

I am relatively new to python and creating regex's is confusing to me so any help on how to parse strings in this way would be very helpful!! If there is a catch 22 here, and not all things I am trying to accomplish are possible let me know.

Comment: What about `The person lives in the U.S.`. Should the final period be removed because it's the end of the sentence? Or not, because it's part of an acronym.

Comment: ["The", "person", "lives", "in", "the", "U.S."] is sufficient. This is another corner case! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Natural language processing on this level is a lot more complex than what a regex can sensibly handle.

Comment: Is the input always going to be a single sentence or are you going to throws multiple sentences at it?

Comment: I actually use a natural language wrapper class to process "the U.S., blonde "bombshell" " into ["the", "U.S.", ",", "blonde", "bombshell"] this is sufficient enough for me to remove commas and periods that stand alone. but I do not know how to remove ["the", "\\"] for example from the output list so I figured a regex would do better

Comment: multiple sentences are used, I am to determine where sentences begin and end but with the help of the wrapper I think my job should be to remove exceptions than use a regex...

Comment: @Max Maybe you should use your wrapper, then use a regex to help with the removing *after* you already parsed it with your wrapper.

Comment: @mbomb007 I know I've gone far in my question but would it still be appropriate to ask how to use a regex to remove these cases? if not I can just ask an entirely new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I understand you are asking specifically about regex, another solution  to your overall problem is to use a library for this express purpose. For instance [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/). It should help you split your strings in sane ways (parsing out the proper punctuation into separate items in a list) which you can then filter out from there.

You are right, the number of corner cases is huge precisely *because* human language is imprecise and vague. Using a library that already accounts for these edge cases should save you a lot of headache.

A helpful primer on dealing with raw text in nltk is [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html). It seems the most useful function for your use case is `nltk.word_tokenize`, which passes back a list of strings with words and punctuation separated.

Comment: The wrapper I use is actually nltk, I now realize I will have to simply remove extraneous words once I've processed them in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python regex that should work for splitting the sentences you provided.

```
((?<![A-Z])\.)*[\W](?<!\.)|[\W]$
```

[**Try it here**](http://pythex.org/?regex=((%3F%3C!%5BA-Z%5D)%5C.)*%5B%5CW%5D(%3F%3C!%5C.)%7C%5B%5CW%5D%24&test_string=The%20R.N.%2C%20lives%20in%20the%20U.S.%20here.%0AThe%20R.N.%2C%20lives%20in%20the%20U.S.&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Since all abbreviations with periods should have a capital letter before the period, we can use a negative lookbehind to exclude those periods:

```
((?<![A-Z])\.)*
```

Then splits on all other non-period non-alphanumerics:

```
[\W](?<!\.)
```

or symbols at the end of a line:

```
|[\W]$
```

I tested the regex on these strings:

`The R.N. lives in the U.S.`

`The R.N., lives in the U.S. here.`