# Edge cases and text formatting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of a larger group project I am working on as a personal challenge, I'm trying to make a function to format a chunk of text into two sentence blocks. The current form of the function is as follows:

```
def format_text(text):
    sentences = text.split('.')    # Split up all sentences using fullstops
    formatted_text = []
# In the actual code, this for loop is actually a list comprehension which looks like:
# formatted_text = ['.'.join([sentences[i-1], sentence]) + '.' for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences) if i % 2 == 1 and len(sentence) != 0]
# Testing with timeit showed it was minimally faster than the for loop.
# Any better suggestions would be well appreciated.
# However I have broken it up here as I feel the extra logic reduces it's readability.
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        if i % 2 == 1:             # i.e for indexes 1, 3,... (every two sentences)
            if len(sentence) != 0:    # If it isn't empty
                # Append the joined sentences to result with extra fullstop (.split() removes the character it splits on)
                formatted_text.append('.'.join([sentences[i-1], sentence]) + '.')
    if len(sentences) % 2 == 1:    # If odd number of sentences, append final, unmatched sentence.
        formatted_text.append(sentences[-1])
    return formatted_text
```

This works pretty well. However, there are some obvious cases in common colloquial text where it fails, as well as cases where it's result is less than ideal. Here are two examples produced using an small excerpt from a BBC article (https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-55916254):

Excerpt:

> But he didn't get where he is by being nice. "If you're not prepared for a meeting with him... and especially if you try to mask that lack of preparedness with smooth talking, he'll know and he will make it clear," Scott Chancellor, a former AWS director told the news portal.
> "People who don't do their best in those meetings won't get a second shot, at least not for a long time."

The two notable ways that this will be processed incorrectly are:

1. The ellipsis at the start of the text will become:

> But he didn't get where he is by being nice. "If you're not prepared for a meeting with him.

> and especially if you try to mask that lack of preparedness with smooth talking,

Ideally this should be ignored, or considered it's own separate symbol to a fullstop.

2. The final speech mark falls at the end of two sentences, as a result it ends up separated from the text is actually associated with:

> "People who don't do their best in those meetings won't get a second shot, at least not for a long time.

> "

Ideally I'd like to keep the function small and fast, but this problem has sort of stumped me. I can't think of a method which doesn't involve iterating through every character in the input string and checking the nearby characters for any edge cases every time it finds a fullstop.

Most related questions I've found seem to be either a mix of 'How do I split a string at all the punctuation marks' or on how to use regex to clean a string of unwanted text. While I admit a almost complete lack of knowledge about using regex, I'm not aware of a way I could use it to ignore punctuation like ellipses, or include a stray speech mark at the end of the string. I've also seen the nltk library mentioned in this question, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006169/regex-to-remove-words-from-a-list-that-are-not-a-z-a-z-exceptions/34006378#34006378", however I'm not sure how I could utilise it for my purpose.

Presumably there's a more elegant solution to this problem which utilises the standard functions provided by python to avoid the runtime slowness caused by the python interpreter. If you have an idea that could help, or a suggestion of where I could look to find one, it would be greatly appreciated!

I'm in the UK and after a few hours of research I'm pretty exhausted given it's 1am. So sorry if I miss any replies!

Comment: Sentence tokeninzing is a solved problem, ref NLTK: https://www.guru99.com/tokenize-words-sentences-nltk.html

Comment: For an ad hoc way to deal with ... replace ... with ELIPSE or some other rare token (or unicode for ...) and then split on the . and then at the end, replace ELIPSE with ... again.

Comment: Someone is going to recommend using regex, regex does a really good job with machine generated text, with natural language, it has its uses, but probably will not work as much as you'd hope. For example, in real natural language, people forget the final punctuation between sentences all the time. Let's see regex wizards tokenized that. Humans tokenize sentences w/o punct or space all the time, so it isn't impossible.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! I'll have a look at that link you sent and your second reply sounds like a good approach for me to take. Would you mind adding this as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided by MatthewMartin in the replies to the original question:

> Sentence tokeninzing is a solved problem, ref NLTK: https://www.guru99.com/tokenize-words-sentences-nltk.html

> For an ad hoc way to deal with ... replace ... with ELIPSE or some other rare token (or unicode for ...) and then split on the . and then at the end, replace ELIPSE with ... again.

> Someone is going to recommend using regex, regex does a really good job with machine generated text, with natural language, it has its uses, but probably will not work as much as you'd hope. For example, in real natural language, people forget the final punctuation between sentences all the time. Let's see regex wizards tokenized that. Humans tokenize sentences w/o punct or space all the time, so it isn't impossible.

Answer is copied in case the originals are deleted.

Comment: You need to include all relevant content into the question itself. If the comment is deleted, then this answer is useless. Then you can mark your own answer as accepted.